# как хранить в БД граф value object

Tags: база-данных, ddd, реляционная-модель

**Задача:** имеется доменная модель состоящая из классов

```
public class EntityA {
    private UUID id;
    private String someValue;
    private Set<ValueObjectA> valueObjects;
    //... остальной код
}

public class ValueObjectA {
    private final String someValue;
    private final Set<ValueObjectB> valueObjects;
    //... остальной код
}

public class ValueObjectB {
    private final String someValue;
    //... остальной код
}
```

Как видно из названия классов - объекты типа EntityA являются сущностями(в терминах DDD), а объекты типов ValueObjectA и ValueObjectB - объектами значениями. Нужно определить каким образом хранить в БД данный граф объектов.

**Что вызвало у меня трудности:** связь между EntityA и ValueObjectA  - один-ко-многим, между ValueObjectA и ValueObjectB тоже один-ко-многим. В этом случае логично для каждого класса создать отдельную таблицу в БД и связать эти таблицы между собой. Проблема возникает в связывании этих таблиц. Я не хочу добавлять в классы ValueObjectA и ValueObjectB идентификаторы, хочу чтобы они остались полноценными value object. В этом случае связать таблицы EntityA и ValueObjectA очень просто, а вот как связать таблицы ValueObjectA и ValueObjectB - я ума не приложу.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала замечу, что для value object неприменимо понятие [мощность cвязи](https://www.bestprog.net/ru/2019/01/27/er-model-the-concept-of-relationship-the-relationship-capacity-types-of-relationships-examples-ru/#q05). Мощность связи определена для связи между сущностями. По-этому, некорректно говорить

> связь между EntityA и ValueObjectA - один-ко-многим

Вы пишете

> не хочу добавлять в классы ValueObjectA и ValueObjectB идентификаторы, хочу чтобы они остались полноценными value object.

Так вам этого и не нужно делать. Для хранения `EntityA.valueObjects` вам нужна таблица `ENTITY_A_VALUE_OBJECT_A`, в которой нужен только внешний ключ на `ENTITY_A.ID`. Репозиторий при загрузке `EntityA` прочитает ассоциированные записи из `ENTITY_A_VALUE_OBJECT_A`. Аналогично для `ValueObjectB` создайте таблицу `ENTITY_A_VALUE_OBJECT_A_VALUE_OBJECT_B` и там точно так же храните внешний ключ на `ENTITY_A`. Своего идентификатора ни у `ValueObjectA` ни у `ValueObjectB` нет и поле в классе не нужно.

Альтернативный вариант это сериализировать `Set<ValueObjectA>` одно значение (может быть строка json/xml/свой формат, или просто массив байт) и хранить в поле в таблице `ENTITY_A`.

Comment: В случае таблицы ENTITY_A_VALUE_OBJECT_A_VALUE_OBJECT_B, если несколько объектов ValueObjectA имеют одинаковые значения поля someValue и принадлежат одному и тому же объекту EntityA, будет невозможно однозначно сопоставить данные объектов ValueObjectB с данными объектов ValueObjectA.

Comment: Точно. Это можно решить введя идентификатор для `ENTITY_A_VALUE_OBJECT_A`. Его можно генерировать как порядковый номер при итерации по `EntityA.valueObjects` при сохранении в БД и не хранить в самом объекте.